# How do use a MOSFET for automatic switching?

Tags: mosfet, oscillator

I'm trying to make an oscillator, but I can't wrap my head around the MOSFET. I have a very simple circuit (drawn in a cellphone paint app) where the circle with an arrow pointed at it is the MOSFET. Please tell me how to arrange the pins so that it will switch itself quickly. If I'm completely wrong on how they work, please tell me.[image]

Comment: If you pulse the FET, the LC loop will ring at resonant frequency and decay with the current across the loop ESR+DCR of C& L respectively or decay with any load R.

Comment: Stop asking basically the same question again and again without answering the requests for more specific information. You obviously have no clue how to build an oscillator nor how to work with MOSFETs. Which is fine but then **educate yourself** and stop asking for a "quick answer" here because you will not get it. Also your schematic doesn't make sense as a MOSFET has 3 terminals, not two.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I've stated I'm clueless when it comes to MOSFETs. I thought I said that I wasn't sure on my schematics, and your comment explains why. I'm sorry for having irritated you, and I'll head to Reddit with my dumb questions.

Comment: "If I'm completely wrong on how they work, please tell me" - You are completely wrong on how they work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's a duplicate of [How can I make the most simple oscillator with my parts?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/549828/how-can-i-make-the-most-simple-oscillator-with-my-parts)

Comment: This connection of a 2-terminal element in series to the LC tank leads me to think of something like a negative resistor... A tempting idea...

Comment: @brhans is completely wrong on how they work. –    It's a valid question

Comment: Maybe the circle is the OP 's head wrapping around the FET bias question

Answer (score 2):

*(edit: Although this newbie question was previously asked and now linked by Moderators, it fails to give an answer)*

Although my initial answer gives a simple way how to pump an LC passive circuit to resonate or oscillate, it doesn't have any feedback to self-regulate and oscillate without the need for a signal generator.

Given the user is new to electronics and has some RLC parts and an Nch FET or NPN transistor, the question is actually, how to make the simplest oscillator at any frequency with an LC circuit was never answered, here is my newest answer below.
It is famously called a Colpitt's Oscillator which is named after the ***[inventor from a century ago.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colpitts_oscillator)***. Wiki explains various different implementations all based on a 180 deg phase shift LC parallel circuit resonating with a 180 deg or negative feedback gain and a net AC positive feedback. The excess loop gain at some frequency or slew rate determines how square the output becomes.

[Here is a browser-based link using javascript by Falstad with my design.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgbALCCsB0AMinJRApgWgBwnrATAJzQTQCMZ0+A7PIfmfNTPDCzJhQFAA2IZ9cFAH5++HKzxIIzKfDJgw9AdGr0s+AMyEIXAMb9BZcYdH58UVmU6tNsHRGLlqZTeMLGwuBPK4AXfi98eBxIEGCJfn4EShIyajBoemhMTWNowg98MCx4rSZU9MZWABM0ADMAQwBXHj99UxAMBUawqxsQCFhVLCYZTTBqCE0e70QyLgB3RuMcfGgvWdwpkE14KHNhQU3l6bXhCCh98Itd1fX+dJHRClF4LgAnc6gwkSFcfmQV47Dj2+Wnj8jhdml5bGt7gAlRqg-iHJotSSdVjQD6SbpcADmzxOwI2CzRXAA8qsqJdRMMbulJFwAB78aCac78IarJnCLwAYQm9LIMhZqIUOHiOA5IE5+C4EHgTNYsKWEEiFAA+hBldRla4SNlldBlXgyJqjVIVGl5lKZasck03DB0oQwfxNMbVQN8Jr4PqfIhCAkFvN9ZrviCWm9YfdyuECUs-iZbWRumNJfTYeIcC45h5OmIQAAFB5oADOhYAOoXIUW0H4y34APZlwtoNANvyVB5+aoABwANGWACIPSqYssAOT0AAsy5UAHYlMsFzs8Sp6ZuFyYASz8k8LI9zI6ns7LAFta9VG7WAG5oB5l4+X1dlybjps8Gv1wsTmeY1cAGTLtZvQtOTfBsmzLcoy0-advy4TRInRFAyDGeQQAASVnao9FbacVy4IA)

[image]

end edit

=========================================

Switches invert the input Voltage.
Pch and PNP on the hi side need low pulses in.
NPN needs +ve pulse to switch to ground.

Here the NPN uses a 1us pulse every 1 ms to charge the Cap limited by the DCR of the inductor resistance and RdsOn of the FET.

If the Pch FET does not pull up to Vcc +12V the 1st time, and it has not decayed from DC series R ( 20m for a good choke )

[image]

JFK&Giggles
[image]

Comment: Apparently this is another ingenious idea of ​​yours... If only I could understand it... For now I only know [how sine oscillations appear in an LC tank](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/How_do_We_Create_Sinusoidal_Oscillations%3F). All that remains is to understand how to maintain them...

Comment: Repetitive pulses will charge the inductor current to the cap voltage towards Vcc then keep ringing till the next pulse.  this is the fundamental of an injection locked loop using  sub harmonics. Which can be done centred around Vcc with a low side switch too

Comment: This evokes a picture from my childhood when my grandmother rocked me, pushing the swing from time to time:)

Comment: But as I can see here, your LC tank is with an external excitation... I only wonder how the exciting pulses and LC oscillations will be synchronized...

Comment: There must be tolerance error and jitter spec for frequency error , to define what is possible.  Lock by injection of hsync pulses  was how old TV's were made for HV flyback sweep oscillators